# Allow short "sessions" for a user with systemd

Tags: systemd, users, gitlab

I'm testing a new gitlab runner I've setup.

If a project just has a very short CI job (or one that fails very quickly, which is probably more realistic outside of testing the setup) systemd starts reporting that "user@999.service" failed, 999 being the uid of gitlab-runner. The job ran as it should, and if it make it slower (e.g. by adding a sleep to it), nothing fails.

Searching for the error leads me to believe it just systemd trying to do something everytime a new "session" starts for that user, and deciding it must be broken because it exits so soon multiple times in a very short period of time. How do I allow that, preferably just for this one user?

Comment: There is a `StartLimitBurst=5` by default, which restricts restarts to 5 in 10 seconds, but I don't think it applies to slice and scope Units.

Comment: I know there are options to configure how many restarts are acceptable for normal services, but this is not a normal service, and if possible I only want to edit it for this one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a more normal unit than I thought.

And by making a `/etc/systemd/system/user@999.service.d/override.conf` (actually `override` doesn't matter, it can be any (there might be some exceptions) string), containing:

```
[Service]
StartLimitBurst=20
```

and running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` the problem disappeared. (I haven't thought much about the value `20`, it is just a number that proved to work)

(If you don't need to automate it, it good way to make such a file is with `sudo systemctl edit user@999.service` - some documentation I found suggested that after making such a file, it is enough to restart the affected service, that's where it seems to be special, at least I haven't figured out how to.)